# Angularjs search product by price (from price to price)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add filter for searching the product by `from price to price`. I have following array in json format as `$scope.products` in the controller.

```
[
  {"product_id":"1","product_price":"185"},
  {"product_id":"2","product_price":"45"},
  {"product_id":"3","product_price":"123"},
  {"product_id":"4","product_price":"23"},
  {"product_id":"5","product_price":"776"}
]
```

And below is the loop in html

```
<ul class="items">
  <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{product_name: findname} | sizeFilter:(size_arr|filter:{on:true})" >
    <strong>{{product.product_name | CapsFirst}}</strong> 
    <strong>({{product.product_category}})</strong>
    <strong>({{product.product_size}})</strong>
    <strong>({{product.product_color}})</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the view I want to add two input fields for searching the products by price.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="from_price" /> 
<input type="number" ng-model="to_price" />
```

Can anyone guide me that I can develop in proper way. I've searched about it but couldn't found a tutorial, I'm not expertise in angularjs. Thank You...

Comment: Where are you using from_price and to_price

Comment: @KannanThangadurai there is only one item inside array `product_price`

Comment: Try  this:

`<div  ng-repeat = "formElement in formElements | filter:filterAge(from_price,to_price)">`

`$scope.filterAge = function(fp,tp) {
  return (product_price > fp && product_price < tp);
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on plunkr of what you've been asking for. I have added a product name in order to distinguish them, try it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/NKos4x9eeB5dZQaypurg?p=preview

```
app.filter('sizeFilter', [function() {
    return function(values, config) {
      if (config.enabled) {
        var filterResult = [];
        angular.forEach(values, function(value) {
          if (value.product_price >= config.from_price && value.product_price <= config.to_price) {
            filterResult.push(value);
          };
        });
        return filterResult;
      }
      return values;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: It does not working when i'm using other filters. There is some conflict

Comment: What filter do you use in addition to provided one? I've made an additional example to filter by name too. Here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/jIDAJsXrfUJFq5n5ACCO?p=preview

Comment: I'm using 3 filters for other purpose

Comment: Can you provide these filters? Because filters themselves are not harming each other as long as they don't change the input model, so maybe it is a load order difference. Please, provide an example of filter that you're using

Comment: This kind of filter i'm using `$scope.color_arr = [];
 angular.forEach($scope.area, function(cd){
  if(cd.product_color!=undefined){
   $scope.color_arr.push(
    {product_color: cd.product_color,
      on: false
    }
   );
  }
 });`

Comment: And in the view i'm calling like this `colorFilter:(color_arr|filter:{on:true})`

Comment: Here is a new example. It uses color_arr[index].on to toggle on/off and color_arr[index].product_color as value to search in products array https://plnkr.co/edit/KLgQyVtEcvMeX1MFuVyf?p=preview

Comment: Yes now you're right but i have two more functions, so if i use this of thing then i have to change my all code

Comment: I appreciate your cooperation and expertise, and i mark as accepted answer. If you want you can still help me to modify my existing code

Comment: Here you go, all filters I've seen from initial fields (with category e.t.c). Hope it'll help https://plnkr.co/edit/tLsEcHNSbwQYeNGe6cxs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
 <li ng-repeat="product in products |rangePrice:
{'toPrice':to_price,'fromPrice':from_price}">
```

In JavaScript

```
app.filter('rangePrice', function() {
    return function( items, rangePrice ) {
        var filteredValue= [];
        var toPrice= parseInt(rangePrice.toPrice);
        var fromPrice= parseInt(rangePrice.fromPrice);
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if( item.product_price>= toPrice&& item.product_price<= toPrice) {
                filteredValue.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filteredValue;
    };
});
```